# how to put sql query in app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, app-config

I want to put all my sql queries in app.config.

I also know how to config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DatabaseConnection" 
        connectionString="Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;uid=npsa;pwd=Password1;Initial Catalog=local;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I know how to connect to database.

Is this possible?

Comment: definitely DON'T DO this! At a minmum, use stored procs.

Comment: @MitchWheat, Matthew: Why ? Is it kind of `bad programming practices` ?

Comment: well, for one, someone could insert malicious code...I guess you could call screwing up your database "bad programming practices "...

Comment: And a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing potentially unsafe code.  The question is likely to inspire code holy wars.

Comment: And a security issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most of the comments above, my answer is "WHY????"

However, assuming you really wanted to and for some reason it was a good idea to do it this way and that you'd worked out how to manage security, then you could add keys to your appsettings e.g.:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Query1" value="Select 1 from somewhere" />
</appSettings>
```

and then in your code you could just pull them out and execute them

```
var sqlString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Query1"];
```

But again, why you would want to do this escapes me.